# Creating custom login errors

Tags: login, errors

I want to be able to create custom login errors.

For instance if a user visits a restricted area without being logged in then I am redirecting to `wp-login.php?ref=access` and I would like to output `Restricted area, please login to continue.` or something similar.

Any idea how to do this. I found that there are filters for `login_errors` but I can't find anywhere else in the code this comes up, except in the login page itself.

Lastly, I really don't want to have to change any of the core files to do this either. I've spent a lot of time and energy trying to make sure that the wordpress core is completely untouched so that I can upgrade it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From quick look at the login screen code (ouch):

```
add_action('login_head','ref_access');

function ref_access() {

    global $error;

    if( !empty($_GET['ref']) && 'access' == $_GET['ref'] )
        $error  = 'Restricted area, please login to continue.';
}
```

Comment: oh, brilliant. :) Thank you. How the hell did you figure that out?! :p Thanks a lot rarst.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson see the code of `login_header()` function. It expects error passed (which would probably require you to add and process custom action, messy) but it also checks that global `$error` variable which is trivial to change as you see. :)

Comment: Please have a look at @Meitar's solution bellow which is way cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

A brief update. As of WordPress version 3.6, using a global variable like Rarst suggests is very messy and it will clobber any other core, plugin, or theme error messages stored in that variable.

The global `error` variable to which Rarst refers is actually [a `WP_Error` object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) which is itself responsible for collating errors from various events across WordPress's invocation lifecycle. So please do not clobber its values, that makes debugging very hard.

Instead, use the `wp_login_errors` filter (not `login_errors`) and `add()` errors there. Like this:

```
add_filter('wp_login_errors', 'my_custom_errors');
function my_custom_error ($errors) {
    if ('access' === $_GET['ref']) {
        $errors->add('access', 'Restricted area, please login to continue.');
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(**NOTE:** This doesn't exactly answer your question.)*

If I am not wrong, the `login_errors` filter that you are talking about is for displaying a message when a wrong username/password is entered.

So, by default, you'd be displayed this when you enter a wrong username:

> **ERROR:** Invalid username.

And this for a wrong password:

> **ERROR:** The password you entered for the username XXXXX is incorrect.

The thing is, you can use the `login_errors` filter to display a custom message:

```
function fake_error(){
    return 'SORRY, LOGIN DISABLED!';
}
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'fake_error' );
```

Generally, used as a security (through obscurity?) measure, used to prevent attacker from knowing whether he's entered a wrong username or a wrong password.